# How do I specify a node type that has docker installed in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use docker to build my code. Not all jenkin slaves have docker installed, so if I just specify:

```
agent {
      dockerfile true
}
```

It fails withe message `"docker not found"`. This I believe because the docker is not installed in that corresponding jenkins slave/master that picked up the job. So my question is: How can I ensure that this jenkins job gets picked by a node that  has docker installed?

If I use:

```
agent {
   node { 
      label 'has-docker'
      dockerfile true
   }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 2: Only one agent type is allowed per agent section @ line 2, column 5.
       agent {
       ^

WorkflowScript: 2: No agent type specified. Must be one of [docker, dockerfile, label, any, none] @ line 2, column 5.
       agent {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide an extra argument `label` inside the `docker` block as documented [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent-parameters).

> **docker**
> Execute the Pipeline, or stage, with the given container which will be dynamically provisioned on a node pre-configured to accept Docker-based Pipelines, or on a node matching the optionally defined `label` parameter.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node:14-alpine' 
            label 'docker-node'
        }
    }
    stages {
        ...
    }
}
```

Its similar if you're using **dockerfile** instead of **docker**.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile {
            filename 'Dockerfile'
            dir 'build'
            label 'docker-node'
        }
    }
    stages {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using two `agent` directives would resolve the issue:

`agent none` for the entire pipeline and a docker `agent` for the specific stage.

Your jenkinsfile should look like this:

```
pipeline{
    agent none
    stages{
        stage('stage_name'){
            agent {
                dockerfile{
                label 'slave-label'
                dir 'relative/location/of/Dockerfile'
                }
            }
           ...
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below one as example. (modify as per your need)

```
agent {
    // Equivalent to "docker build -f Dockerfile.build --build-arg version=1.0.2 ./build/
    dockerfile {
        filename 'Dockerfile.build'
        dir 'build'
        label 'my-defined-label'
        additionalBuildArgs  '--build-arg version=1.0.2'
        args '-v /tmp:/tmp'
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to give the agents that have docker installed a common label and use that label inside the agent section for the pipeline. The jenkins documentation state the following for the `label` tag when defining a node.

> Labels (or tags) are used to group multiple agents into one logical
>   group. For example, if you have multiple Windows agents and you have a
>   job that must run on Windows, then you could configure all your
>   Windows agents to have the label windows, and then tie that job to
>   this label.  This would ensure that your job runs on one of your
>   Windows agents, but not on any agents without this label.
>
> Labels do not necessarily have to represent the operating system on
>   the agent; you can also use labels to note the CPU architecture, or
>   that a certain tool is installed on the agent.
>
> Multiple labels must be separated by a space. For example, windows
>   docker would assign two labels to the agent: windows and docker.
>
> Labels may contain any non-space characters, but you should avoid
>   special characters such as any of these: !&|<>(), as other Jenkins
>   features allow for defining label expressions, where these characters
>   may be used.

In your case, do the same by labeling nodes that have docker installed with a common label such as `docker

As for the error you are encountering, the fix is mentioned [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44202?focusedCommentId=304424&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-304424)

```
agent {
    docker {
        dockerfile true
        label 'docker'
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot specify `dockerfile` in the `docker` closure so the above fix doesn't work